# TreeWalker shows invisible nodes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have dom tree with div with `display: none`:

```
<div id="root">
    1
    <div style="display: none;">
        2
    </div>
    3
</div>
```

I iterate through this dom tree using `TreeWalker`:

```
let element = document.getElementById('root');
let walker = document.createTreeWalker(element, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL);

while (walker.nextNode()) {
    let node = walker.currentNode;
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        console.log(node.nodeValue.trim());
    }
}
```

From [MDN documentation to `TreeWalker.nextNode()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker/nextNode):

> The TreeWalker.nextNode() method moves the current Node to the **next visible node** in the document order ...

So, I think that div with `display: none` should be skipped by `TreeWalker`. But it isn't:

```js
let element = document.getElementById('root');
let walker = document.createTreeWalker(element, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL);

while (walker.nextNode()) {
    let node = walker.currentNode;
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        console.log(node.nodeValue.trim());
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
    1
    <div style="display: none;">
        this text node shouldn't be obtained with TreeWalker
    </div>
    3
</div>
```

So, why it isn't skipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because *visible* term in this case doesn't belong to

> visible in dom

Instead it belongs to

- fit the [`TreeWalker.whatToShow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker/whatToShow) mask *and*
- is accepted by [`TreeWalker.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker/filter)